# Regular expression + Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I would like to validate my users, so they can only use a-z and `-` in their username.

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /[a-z]/
```

However this rule also allows `_` `-` and capital letters. How do I only allow letters, numbers, `_` and `-`?

Answer (score 3):

This regex makes sure that the first character is a lowercase letter and the rest are either lowercase letters, numbers, hyphens or underscores.

```
/\A[a-z][a-z0-9_-]+\Z/
```

If you don't care about the first character, you can use

```
/\A[a-z0-9_-]+\Z/
```

If you want to make sure the name is minimum 4 characters long:

```
/\A[a-z][a-z0-9_-]{3,}\Z/
```

If you want to make sure the length is between 4 and 8

```
/\A[a-z][a-z0-9_-]{3,7}\Z/
```

If the length should be 6

```
/\A[a-z][a-z0-9_-]{5}\Z/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is not specific enough. You're looking for something like:

```
:with => /\A[a-z_]+\Z/
```